# Get previous posts list

Tags: query, date, previous, comparison

I'll give up. Have searched and searched and tried and tried... Can't find any solution to list previous posts.

On a single post: I want to show a list of the 10 previous posts, the 10 before the current post. So, not just a two prev and next links. Not the most recent posts that is. A list of the the 10 previous posts before the current post you are visiting.

I'm trying to make a query and comparing `post_date` lower than `get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. But it's not working. I guess post_date isn't an allowed key to use in `'compare'`.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The code right now:

```
<?php
$posts_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10
  , 'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'post_date'
          , 'compare' => '<'
          , 'value'   => get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        )
      )
);
$myposts = query_posts($posts_args);
?>
```

Comment: Please post all of your relevant code.

Comment: I change it continuously cause I'm testing different things. But look at my edit now.

Comment: i think you are doing this for auto linking? did you achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you chceck the [Codex Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) ? Expecially the 'before' param.
It works like this:

```
$date = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before' => $date
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Strange. Some how, this code makes the page doing an redirection to the "Hello world" (first) post.

Comment: Aha, I needed `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`